# Reading Items on Outlook Shared Tasks with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, outlook, shared

i got a question about Shared-Tasks in Outlook.
The Shared-Tasks List is from a Microsoft Exchange Server.

```
$Outlook = New-Object -ComObject Outlook.Application

$OutlookTasks = $Outlook.session.GetDefaultFolder(13)

$OutlookTasks = $Outlook.session.GetDefaultFolder(13).Items

$OutlookTasks | ft Subject, Body
```

This shows me only my own Task in Powershell.

```
Subject Body   
------- ----   
Test    Task
```

But i want to access a Shared-Tasks List, which is listed below from "My Tasks".

It looks like this:

[Outlook View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L8yNv.png)

Is there a command to go deeper into my Tasks ?

Comment: I dont think so; What exactly you meant by shared ? Is it like a shared mailbox for that you want to get the details? Then yes, you can get that

Comment: As shown on the picture i link to the question, its a shared Task. Its shared over Microsoft Exchange Server. You can creat normal Task in Outlook and share them with other. Thats what a colleague did and now i want to read this Task.

Comment: Not possible to get that. Unless some COM object is linked with it which I might not be aware of .